# If $|x_{n+1} - a| \le C|x_n - a|^2$ how close does $x_1$ need to be to $a$ so that the sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, optimization

Edit: Thank you for helping me out with the title. New to asking mathematics questions like this!

Then it says determine the limits. We're asked this question in my real analysis and I'm not sure where to begin, because it seems a bit over my head. Do I use the definition of a limit?

Any pointers toward getting this started would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much you guys!

Comment: No problem about the edit! Does the left hand side (LHS) has a square or not? Also, can we assume $C \le1$?

Comment: Show that 
$$|x_n-a|\leq C^{-1}\Big(C|x_1-a|\Big)^{2^{n-1}}$$
for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: The LHS does not have a square. I'm not sure about C. He states that this type of inequality is used in optimization, of which I have no experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $a=0$, this is
$|x_{n+1}| \le c|x_n|^2$.

To have 
$|x_{n+1}| \le |x_n|$.,
we want
$c|x_n|^2 \le |x_n|$
or $|x_n| \le 1/c$.

With $a$, this is
$|x_n-a| \le 1/c$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This made me understand it a lot better.